# Convergence Of $z^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

To find the limit function of $f_n(z)=z^n$ on the unit disk we have to look at different cases of the value of $z$ to do so on the complex plane we have to look at $|z|$ because the is no "order" on the complex numbers.

So for $|z|<1$:  $|f_n(z)|=|z^n|=|z|^n$ so $f(z)=0$

For $|z|=1$: if $z=1$ so $f(z)=1$ but is $z\neq 1$ that mean that $z=e^{i\theta}$ f(z) will not converge.

So in the complex series functions we have to set $|z|$ and look at $z$ (and vice versa) and then see what happens as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: In this case, yes, you have to do that